# Swift changing button height depending on screen size

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, xcode8

So I have a button/image, and I want to get higher/smaller when viewing on iPad or a smaller iPhone.

In Xcode >7 I could put my items inside W/all H/all, then I could put constraint in compact width/any height if I wanted it to be in iPhone portrait. But in Xcode 8 its a whole new system and I don't know how to do it now, so I want to change my height of the button depending on the size of the screen, how to do that?

I've tried to search around on the net, and find something with make a constraint outlet. Could that work if I have autolayout on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

**Swift 3**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonWidthContraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonHeightContraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        buttonHeightContraint.constant = (screenSize.height / 2)
        buttonWidthContraint.constant = (screenSize.width / 2)

    }
}
```

**Swift 2**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonWidthContraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonHeightContraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        buttonHeightContraint.constant = (screenSize.height / 2)
        buttonWidthContraint.constant = (screenSize.width / 2)

    }
}
```

This way the `UIButton.height` is always the size of the screen / 2.

Just have a look for the right quotient you need. For example `(screenSize.height / 25.3)`, then on iPad, on every iPhone and so on, the Button will always have the height, depending on the device.

Another possibility would be the `UIDeviceExtension`

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

public extension UIDevice {

    var modelName: String {
        var systemInfo = utsname()
        uname(&systemInfo)
        let machineMirror = Mirror(reflecting: systemInfo.machine)
        let identifier = machineMirror.children.reduce("") { identifier, element in
            guard let value = element.value as? Int8 where value != 0 else { return identifier }
            return identifier + String(UnicodeScalar(UInt8(value)))
        }

        switch identifier {
        case "iPod5,1":                                 return "iPod Touch 5"
        case "iPod7,1":                                 return "iPod Touch 6"
        case "iPhone3,1", "iPhone3,2", "iPhone3,3":     return "iPhone 4"
        case "iPhone4,1":                               return "iPhone 4s"
        case "iPhone5,1", "iPhone5,2":                  return "iPhone 5"
        case "iPhone5,3", "iPhone5,4":                  return "iPhone 5c"
        case "iPhone6,1", "iPhone6,2":                  return "iPhone 5s"
        case "iPhone7,2":                               return "iPhone 6"
        case "iPhone7,1":                               return "iPhone 6 Plus"
        case "iPhone8,1":                               return "iPhone 6s"
        case "iPhone8,2":                               return "iPhone 6s Plus"
        case "iPad2,1", "iPad2,2", "iPad2,3", "iPad2,4":return "iPad 2"
        case "iPad3,1", "iPad3,2", "iPad3,3":           return "iPad 3"
        case "iPad3,4", "iPad3,5", "iPad3,6":           return "iPad 4"
        case "iPad4,1", "iPad4,2", "iPad4,3":           return "iPad Air"
        case "iPad5,3", "iPad5,4":                      return "iPad Air 2"
        case "iPad2,5", "iPad2,6", "iPad2,7":           return "iPad Mini"
        case "iPad4,4", "iPad4,5", "iPad4,6":           return "iPad Mini 2"
        case "iPad4,7", "iPad4,8", "iPad4,9":           return "iPad Mini 3"
        case "iPad5,1", "iPad5,2":                      return "iPad Mini 4"
        case "iPad6,7", "iPad6,8":                      return "iPad Pro"
        case "iPad2,1", "iPad2,2", "iPad2,3", "iPad2,4", "iPad3,1", "iPad3,2", "iPad3,3", "iPad3,4", "iPad3,5", "iPad3,6", "iPad4,1", "iPad4,2", "iPad4,3", "iPad5,3", "iPad5,4", "iPad2,5", "iPad2,6", "iPad2,7", "iPad4,4", "iPad4,5", "iPad4,6", "iPad4,7", "iPad4,8", "iPad4,9", "iPad5,1", "iPad5,2":                       return "iPad"
        case "AppleTV5,3":                              return "Apple TV"
        case "i386", "x86_64":                          return "Simulator"
        default:                                        return identifier
        }
    }

}
```

Used as following (for example):

```
let modelName = UIDevice.currentDevice().modelName
if modelName == "iPad" {
    buttonOutlet.frame.size.height =  42
} else if modelName == "iPhone 4" {
    buttonOutlet.frame.size.height =  25
}
```

And so on.

Comment: This sounds like a great idea but i get the error NSLayoutConstraint has no memer frame?

Comment: because you did put the outlet on the constraint and not on the button

Comment: you have to set the layout on the button itself, not on the height constraint of the button for example

Comment: It doesn't seem to work i tried setting it to screen.height / 2 just for test but nothing changed, is there some constraints i need?

Comment: I'll edit my answer to hope to have it working for you. Gimme a sec

Comment: @JonathanHelding see my edit. i tried it in both swift 2 and 3. works for me. button is with this code (screenSize /2)

Comment: i have used now the way to set the width and the height constraint constant

Comment: That did work thank you!! i was looking at your code using the switch, if screenSize.height couldn't you do something like
if screenSide.height <= 420 {buttonHeightConstraint.constant = 100}

Comment: glad to help buddy. don't restrain from voting "up" as well :P `code using the switch, if screenSize.height couldn't you do something like`. i don't got that. what do you mean?

Comment: I mean if you already have the value of the screen height, so let's say the value of 6s height is 667 then could could just if screenHeight = 667 {buttonHeightConstraint = 100}?

Comment: in theory i suppose you could do that, but consider the extension i've provided, there aren't even the iphone9,1 and so on entered (iPhone 7/Plus). have a deeper look at it... there are already over 20 devices with different views. i wouldn't use a constant like `667`. also you have to look into the future. there will new devices come. do you want to re-create the code every other year? better use a reusable value like `let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds`

Comment: that way you can be sure your code will work on EVERY possible device, now and in the future

Comment: This extension is unnecessary. OP just wants to distinguish between iPad and iPhone and that what 'UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom' is for.

Comment: @Kubba op did used another suggestion anyways. just wanted to provide with a possibility to distinguish between every possible device

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do this without code, using size classes you can use compact width size class which applies to all iPhones in all orientations (except large iPhones in landscape like iPhone6 plus). Compact width matches iPads only in split screen.

To add vairant:
- add height constraint to your button and set it to i.e. 50 (this will add constraint for `any/any` size class):

- select constraint on storyboard
- click on size inspector (fifth tab on right window)
- click on little plus icon next to `Constant`
- select `compact` for width and `any` for others
- now edit height constant for `wC` and set it to i.e. 30

Other way is to use `UIUserInterfaceIdiom` enum in set height in code, i.e. like this:

```
if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
    //adjust size for iPads
}else{
    //adjust size for others
}
```

Comment: It would be best to do it out code, but how do i chose compact width in xcode 8?

Comment: I've chose to do it another way, but i will defiantly keep this in mind, take my up vote :D